# How to commit files with active handles using SharpSvn?

Tags: c#, sharpsvn

My C# application uses SharpSVN to synchronize local (working copies) and remote (repositories) files. Since I want to synchronize these files while they are processes by other applications, it can be that modified files have active handles at commit time.
When I try to commit these files, I receive the following error:

> SvnSystemException: "Can't open file 'somefile.ext': File is used by another process"
>
> WindowsErrorCode: ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION

However when I manually commit them using TortoiseSVN it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meanwhile I found [this thread](http://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=728&dsMessageId=330731). It seems that SharpSvn doesn't allow that files that are about to be committed are in a writable state.

So, the correct answer to my initial question is: **"It's not possible as long as the files are writable"**. Anyway, in my case the workaround for committing opened files (AutoCAD drawings) is to set them readonly on System level.